# Laravel allways keeping return 'This action is unauthorized.'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, policy

- Laravel version: 9
- PHP: 8.1.1

I made a Policy `ProductPolicy` for a model and I wanted to check every time if a user can update/delete a product. But if I authorize this action inside my `ProductController` it keeps returning `This action is unauthorized`.

I'm using the default `Request` class and I set the policy to the model on the `AuthServiceProvider`.

These are my files:

##### api.php

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'token/{token}',
    'middleware' => 'token'
], function () {
    Route::apiResource('category', \App\Http\Controllers\Category\CategoryController::class);
    Route::apiResource('product', \App\Http\Controllers\Product\ProductController::class);
});
```

##### ProductContoller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Product;

use App\Facades\CurrentBot;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Bot;
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Response
     * @throws AuthorizationException
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', [$product]);

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'string',
            'description' => 'string',
            'amount' => 'numeric',
            'thumb' => 'file|max:2048'
        ]);

        $product->fill($request->all());

        if ($request->file('thumb')) {
            $save = $request->file('thumb')->store('/public/images');
            $product->thumb = $save;
        }

        return response($product->save());
    }
}
```

##### Product

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'thumb',
        'amount',
        'category_id'
    ];
}
```

##### ProductPolicy

```php
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Facades\CurrentBot;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class ProductPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Response|bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Product $product): Response|bool
    {
        return CurrentBot::me()->categories()->whereHas('products',  function (Builder $query) use ($product) {
            return $query->where('id', $product->id);
        })->exists();
    }
}
```

I did a lot of search on google. There are only 2 solution:

1. Is setting the `authorize` function to `false` inside the `Request` class which I made.
2. Is adding a model and policy class to `AuthServiceProvider`.

But I'm using a custom request class and I've set the model and policy class even they have the same name in `AuthServiceProvider` like this:

```php
protected $policies = [
    Product::class => ProductPolicy::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but it's worked when I changed my policy code from

```
public function update(User $user, Product $product): Response|bool
{
    return CurrentBot::me()->categories()->whereHas('products',  function (Builder $query) use ($product) {
        return $query->where('id', $product->id);
    })->exists();
}
```

to

```
public function update(?User $user, Product $product): Response|bool
{
    return CurrentBot::me()->categories()->whereHas('products',  function (Builder $query) use ($product) {
        return $query->where('id', $product->id);
    })->exists();
}
```